# Parse infix expression while keeping delimiters as array element

Tags: c#, algorithm, parsing

Does C# have a way for me to parse something like this:

```
 "(h1+h2+h3)" into a string array {"(", "h1", "+", "h2", +, "h3", + ")"} ?
```

I am implementing **Shunting-yard algorithm** and I don't want to make a work around for not having tokens.

[Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Edit: I just wrote my own solution

```
private string[] parseExp(string exp)
{
        // it will be at least as long as the input string
        string[] parsed = new string[exp.Length];
        int index = 0;

        foreach(char c in exp)
        {
            if(op.Contains(c))
            {
                index++;
                parsed[index++] += c.ToString();
            }else
            {
                parsed[index] += c.ToString();
            }
        }

        Array.Resize(ref parsed, index + 1);

        return parsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rearrange your expression so that you can split it using String.Split operation but in that case you need to know all possible symbols your expression can have.

```
string input="(h1+h2+h3)";
String newString = input.Replace("("," ( ").Replace(")"," ) 
"
).Replace("+"," + "); // Reformat string by separating symbols
String[] splitStr = newString.Split(new char[]{' '});
foreach(string x in splitStr)
{
  Console.WriteLine(x);    
}
```